# What exactly does the timeZone option do in Intl.DateTimeFormat()

Tags: javascript, timestamp, timezone, utc, gmt

I have difficulties to understand what the `timeZone` option in the `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` method exactly does. I could not find an in-depth resource on this, yet. Any explanation would be much appreciated.

*Background: We need to display the timestamp of a backend server on the frontend and had some issues with the timezone offset. At the moment, I believe the solution to display the correct time depending on the local client time is the following:*

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
          hour: 'numeric',
          minute: 'numeric',
          second: 'numeric',
          timeZone: 'GMT'
        }).format(timestamp)}
```

*I do not fully understand, why I need to pass the option timeZone: 'GMT' for "Greenwich Mean Time' to get the correct time on the frontend.*

Comment: Date objects are time-zone aware. When you display a date you need to select the time zone for obvious reasons. I'm not entirely sure though of what your doubt is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The time zone is used to calculate the local time:

```js
const timeZones = [
    "GMT",
    "Europe/Madrid",
    "Asia/Tokyo"
];
const timestamp = new Date();
let displayDate;
for (timeZone of timeZones) {
    displayDate = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
        second: 'numeric',
        timeZone: timeZone
    }).format(timestamp);
    console.log("%s @ %s", displayDate, timeZone);
}
```

If omitted altogether, it will default to current local time zone in the JavaScript runtime where the code runs:

```js
let displayDate = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
}).format(new Date());
console.log(displayDate);
```

So the property can be used to make it explicit/static or to be able to use other time zones.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have got another question: If I don't specify the timezone, the runtime environment will bring in its timezone and thus add an offset to the timestamp that otherwise would correspond to the GMT time (which has no offset?).

Comment: That's not exactly how dates work in JavaScript. A `Date` object points to an exact (absolute) moment in time (I don't know the internal format, perhaps it's a mere Unix time, but I'm speculating). It's whenever the runtime needs to generate a (relative) local time when time zone is needed (and considered).

Comment: What about if you want to get the local timezone set to the current computer? I guess you skip this parameter?

Comment: @Vladyn Yes, you skip it. I've updated the answer with that.